# How to change default files matches of unit test in vue-cli 3

Tags: vue-cli-3

I'm using vue-cli 3.0 and created project with manual features selecting unit test(mocha + chai). Default files matches are: any files in `tests/unit` that end in `.spec.(ts|js)`. Is there any way to change target directory and files pattern?

I want to change the target directory from `tests/unit` to `root directory` where the package.json file is. But I cannot find how to change target directory.

And I tried this to change file pattern. But it doesn't work.

```
"scripts": {
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit --glob '*.test.js'"
}
```

I read this also: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1245. I need what `@iamceege` said exactly. Should I set test environment by myself without default setting?

Answer (score 3):

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
   ...,
   "test": "vue-cli-service test:unit --watch --recursive 'src/**/*_test.ts'",
   ...
},
```

**Official documentation:**

[Unit test plugin parameters (mocha)](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha)

[Arguments of the webpack (mocha)](http://zinserjan.github.io/mocha-webpack/docs/installation/cli-usage.html)

Comment: It does not work. It only works for tests in `tests/unit` folder. Plus, it doesn't change files matches also... Did you try before you answered?

Comment: My example work if tests in the 'src' directory or subfolders. I don't see your code. But  I tried run tests in the root of project and subfolders with this is mask:
     "test": "vue-cli-service test:unit --watch ./**/*test.js ./*test.js"
It's work

Comment: **other variant with exclude 'node_modules' directory:** `"test": "vue-cli-service test:unit --watch $(find . -type f -not -path '*node_modules*' -name '*test.js')"`

Answer (score 1):

try without the single quotes around the blob

```
"scripts": {
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit --glob *.test.js"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `jest.config.js` file you can define a `testMatch` variable. Full options [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testmatch-arraystring).

Since you want the root directory, you could try something like:

```
// inside jest.config.js
    testMatch: [
      '*.test.js']
```

Note you can chain multiple selectors in the array.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code ,work for me

```
yarn test:unit --  --runTestsByPath tests/unit/convert-time-frame.spec.js
```